# GWT 2.5.1 SuperDevMode not enabled

Tags: gwt, mgwt, gwt-2.5, gwt-super-dev-mode

i work on a GWT/GWTPHONEGAP/MGWT project and i need using gwt 2.5.1 with SuperdevMode.

I use maven and the following command "classpath gwt:runcodeServer", when i compile my project no error occur, but when i go to my webBrowser to using superDevMode, it's impossible to recompile, the error message is "this module has doesn't have Super Dev mode enabled" although my ***.gwt.xml contains the following line enabled superDevMode.

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
      <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
      <set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true" />
```

with following entrypoint

```
  <entry-point class="**.**.*.client.MgwtAppEntryPoint" />
```

When i go to the localhost:9876 the project is present & source are available.

Following my configuration of maven :

jetty :

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>9.1.2.v20140210</version>

                        <configuration>

                            <reload>manual</reload>


                            <httpConnector>
                                <port>9090</port><!-- port 8080 already use by tiviz-web -->
                            </httpConnector>

                            <webApp>

                                <baseResource implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection">
                                    <resourcesAsCSV>src/main/webapp,${basedir}/target/tiviz-gwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</resourcesAsCSV>
                                </baseResource>
                                <extraClasspath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</extraClasspath>
                                <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>

                            </webApp>

                            <systemProperties>
                                    <systemProperty>
                                        <name>gwt.codeserver.port</name>
                                        <value>9876</value>
                                    </systemProperty>
                            </systemProperties>

                        </configuration>

                    </plugin>
```

and my configuration of gwt-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                    documentation at codehaus.org -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- run params -->
                    <copyWebapp>false</copyWebapp>
                    <productionMode>false</productionMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: which browser are you using? Can you add the bookmarks?

Comment: yes, i can add the bookmark, & i use chrome, when i use eclipse and run with google plugin (http://127.0.0.1:8888/**.html?codeServer..) without the codeServer parts, i am available to using super dev mode so i am pretty sur that's the probleme come from my jetty server but i don't know where

Comment: can you switch to GWT 2.6.1 and try again.

Comment: unfortunately, mgwt don't support GWT 2.6.1, next release must be support .. but i have understood that SuperDevMode was introduced with GWT 2.5.1

Comment: problem come from an bad configuration in the path of my webapp ressource in jetty plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem come from an bad configuration in the path of my webapp ressource in jetty plugin.